# How to calculate all possible multiple choice combinations?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following multiple choice question:

> What's the color of apples?
>
> - a. red
> - b. green
> - c. blue
> - d. black

Now, I want to calculate all it's possible answers and I could do it manually, like so...:

```
a
b
c
d
a, b
a, c
a, d
b, c
b, d
c, d
a, b, c
a, b, d
a, c, d
b, c, d
a, b, c, d
```

... but that's prone to human error. How could I do this programmatically with JavaScript?

My initial thought is to define the total number of choices (a,b,c,d = 4)...:

```
const TOTAL_CHOICES = 4;

// TO-DO
```

... but then I don't know what the next step should be. Any ideas?

Comment: A search for "permutations and combinations" will give you all the background info you need to compute the possible combinations of answers. Some calculators have a nCr / nPr button - for solving just these kinds of problems.

Comment: Take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/generating-all-combinations-of-an-array you can get https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1101/

Comment: Math.Pow(2,NUMCHOICES) gives you the number of choices, assuming "none of the above" is a possibility. If there has to be at least one choice, subtract 1 from that.

Comment: And then if you actually want to list them, run through the the numbers 0 to (2^n)-1 (or 1 to (2^n)-1 if there has to be at least one answer), represent the number in binary, and if there is a 1 in the place corresponding to a given element (so for instance in your example put a in the 1's place, b in the 2's,c in the 4's, and d in the 8's), list it in that group of choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @nenad-vracar's comment I found a solution:

```
function combinations(str) {
  var fn = function(active, rest, a) {
    if (!active && !rest)
      return;
    if (!rest) {
      a.push(active);
    } else {
      fn(active + rest[0], rest.slice(1), a);
      fn(active, rest.slice(1), a);
    }
    return a;
  }
  return fn("", str, []);
}

var result = combinations('abcd').sort();

for (combination of result) {
    document.body.innerHTML += combination + '<br>';
}
```

This will output:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abd
ac
acd
ad
b
bc
bcd
bd
c
cd
d
```

Answer (score 0):

This implements the way I suggested in my comment.

```
var choices = ['d','c','b','a'];
var numCombos=Math.pow(2,choices.length);
var binNum;
writeln('Combos are:');
for (i=0;i<numCombos;i++)
{
 binNum=(i.toString(2));
 while (binNum.length<choices.length)
  binNum='0'+binNum;
 for (j=choices.length-1;j>=0;j--){
   if (binNum[j]=='1') write(choices[j]);}
 writeln();
}
```

Comment: This ran in the online runner I was using, but you might want to add "document." before write and writeln to make it more portable.